# What is the purpose of const pointer to void

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

Do you find it strange that `pthread_setspecific` needs const void pointer but `pthread_getspecific` returns non-const void pointer?

```
void *pthread_getspecific(pthread_key_t key);
int pthread_setspecific(pthread_key_t key, const void *value);
```

[The link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_setspecific.html).

Comment: I see in the above a `pointer to constant something`, not a `constant pointer to something`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Meh, just another const-unsafe C interface. In truth, though, it's quite impossible to create a `const`-safe version of this. If both functions are consistent, then either people who want to store pointers-to-`const` must cast away `const` when storing the pointer, or people who want to store pointers-to-non-`const` must cast away `const` when retrieving the pointer.
The way it is, it's not safe, but at least it doesn't force you to clutter the code with casts.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: because you give to `pthread_setspecific` a `const` pointer, and you can get it back non-`const` via `pthread_getspecific`, so if your original pointer was `const` now you get the `const` casted away.

Comment: OK. If the pointer returned by `pthread_getspecific()` points to the same object as does the pointer given to `pthread_setspecific()`, then this makes sense.

Comment: I'm gonna throw my support into this as well. It's true there is no const-correct way to do this, but the "gotcha" is worth noting.

Answer (score 4):

It is to indicate that the value pointed to is not modified by pthread_setspecific(). You are free to modify the value pointed to by the return of pthread_getspecific().

Comment: ... which is `const` unsafe (`pthread_getspecific` drops the `const` that might have been on the original pointer); still, any other way would be a useless complication.

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_setspecific` only states, that this function doesn't modify `value`. You can pass it non-const stuff..

Comment: The gotcha is that, on the other hand, it allows you to pass `const` pointers, but `pthread_getspecific` returns a non-`const` pointer in any case, thus discarding the `const` if it was present.

Answer (score -2):

These are getter and setter functions whose prototypes remain like this across many languages.

Comment: whoever done -1 look at history of POSIX thread library and their function prototypes then downvote it.